# Jquery time difference in hours from two fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I have two fields in my form where users select an input time (start_time, end_time) I would like to, on the change of these fields, recalcuate the value for another field.

What I would like to do is get the amount of hours between 2 times. So for instance if I have a start_time of 5:30 and an end time of 7:50, I would like to put the result 2:33 into another field.

My inputted form times are in the format HH:MM:SS

So far I have tried...

```
$('#start_time,#end_time').on('change',function() 
{
  var start_time = $('#start_time').val();
  var end_time = $('#end_time').val();

    var diff =  new Date(end_time) - new Date( start_time);  



  $('#setup_hours').val(diff);
```

Comment: `2:33`, `2.33` or `2:20` instead ?

Comment: or `new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time)`. is just a time on its own a date? dont think so...

Comment: 2.33 The second part of the decimal should be the percentage of a total hour. So 2:20 in this case 20/60 is .33

Comment: there is no date included in the input it is simply just "HH:MM:SS"

Comment: @lifeinthefridge, so use a constant date piece

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
var diff = ( new Date("1970-1-1 " + end_time) - new Date("1970-1-1 " + start_time) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

[have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZBNN/)

Comment: I am getting a NaN result returned from this? This is also the issue I'm having given trying to use this answer as well?

Comment: For ex. i have new Date("1970-1-1 12:00 ") - new Date("1970-1-1 10:55") ) / 1000 / 60 / 60. The **answer** is 1.083333... **1** is the HOUR, but why **0.83** for the minutes ? It seems like the answer is **1.05** 1hour & 5 minutes? I'm a bit confused. 

Maybe this one gets the correct answer http://jsfiddle.net/VDnND/

Comment: @aldrien no its 1.083 hours. if you want the TOTAL minutes just times 1.083333 by 60 - seconds by another 60 etc. The OP did ask for hours, there's always abs()

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what format you want your output in. When doing math with Date objects, it converts them into milliseconds since Epoch time (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC).  By subtracting the two (and taking absolute value if you don't know which is greater) you get the raw number of *milliseconds* between the two.

From there, you can convert it into whatever format you want. To get the number of seconds, just divide that number by `1000`. To get hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
var diff =  Math.abs(new Date(end_time) - new Date(start_time));
var seconds = Math.floor(diff/1000); //ignore any left over units smaller than a second
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60); 
seconds = seconds % 60;
var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
minutes = minutes % 60;

alert("Diff = " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

You could of course make this smarter with some conditionals, but this is just to show you that using math you can format it in whatever form you want. Just keep in mind that a Date object always has a date, not just a time, so you can store this in a Date object but if it is greater than 24 hours you will end up with information not really representing a "distance" between the two.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response! While, this isn't necesarily the exact method I used for formatting the time, this post helped me get a better understanding of the date function and posiblities.

Answer (score 6):

```
   var start = '5:30';
   var end = '7:50';
   s = start.split(':');
   e = end.split(':');
   min = e[1]-s[1];
   hour_carry = 0;
   if(min < 0){
       min += 60;
       hour_carry += 1;
   }
   hour = e[0]-s[0]-hour_carry;
   min = ((min/60)*100).toString()
   diff = hour + ":" + min.substring(0,2);
   alert(diff);
```

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
var diff = new Date("Aug 08 2012 9:30") - new Date("Aug 08 2012 5:30");
diff_time = diff/(60*60*1000);
```

Comment: I am getting a NaN result returned from this if I use any minute value greater than 23?  Weird... However, I am getting a very large number returned which I assume is the raw milliseconds as ngmiceli mentioned before that.