# How to calculate the difference between 2 HTML5 time input types

Tags: jquery, html, time

I have a form containing two input type="time" fields. I have a third input type="time" field called 'delay' on the form that I would like to use jQuery to update based on the difference between the two times.

I have searched for an answer but so far have not been able to come up with a solution that works. Since the input type="time" fields only contain hours/minutes I've tried something like this:

```
<input type="time" id="timeOfCall">
<input type="time" id="timeOfResponse">

var timeOfCall = $('#timeOfCall').val();
var timeOfResponse = $('#timeOfResponse').val();
var diff = new Date("Aug 08 2012" + timeOfCall) - new Date("Aug 08 2012" + timeOfResponse);
var timeDifference = diff/(60*60*1000);
```

However this does not work. I get NaN responses when I use this. I got this code from [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields) and the person who asked the question there also got the same NaN issue, but unhelpfully found a solution to the problem without posting what it was.

I've also tried this:

```
var timeDifference = new Date("1970-1-1 " + timeOfCall) - new Date("1970-1-1 " +  timeOfResponse) ) / 1000 / 60 / 60;
```

This definitely comes the closest to working but it gives some odd results sometimes. For instance, if timeOfCall is 01:01 and timeOfResponse is 03:03 it gives a difference of 2.033333....

In either case I also cannot get the 'delay' time field to update in either case.

```
$('#delay').val(timeDifference);
```

Simply does nothing. I would really appreciate any and all assistance with this, I have been going at it for the past few days with no success and no real clue how to go about fixing it. I've been doing a lot of Googling but very few results actually seem to pertain to HTML5 input type="time" fields so I've had no luck so far.

**Edit:** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TFjG/)

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @PalashMondal Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3TFjG/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be just like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uWT4r/)

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var timeOfCall = $('#timeOfCall').val(),
        timeOfResponse = $('#timeOfResponse').val(),
        hours = timeOfResponse.split(':')[0] - timeOfCall.split(':')[0],
        minutes = timeOfResponse.split(':')[1] - timeOfCall.split(':')[1];

    minutes = minutes.toString().length<2?'0'+minutes:minutes;
    if(minutes<0){ 
        hours--;
        minutes = 60 + minutes;
    }
    hours = hours.toString().length<2?'0'+hours:hours;
    $('#delay').val(hours + ':' + minutes);
});
```

Comment: There is a slight issue with it roasted. If the minutes on the left hand side are greater than the minutes on the right hand side, nothing gets displayed. How would you suggest going about fixing it?

Comment: How to do it using Javascript instead of jquery?

Comment: `01:00 AM - 01:00 AM` yield `12:00 AM` Is it Okay?