# How can I calculate time duration for the same day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As I am using **input type= "time"** therefore both of the time value have am and pm that add difference in the time value. First I need to get those values and through them I want to calculate the duration.

```html
<form>
    <label>Start Time</label> 
<input type="time" name ="start_time" id ="start_time" value="" onchange="timeDuration()">

<label>End Time</label>  
<input type="time" name ="end_time" id ="end_time" value="" onchange="timeDuration()">
<label>Time Duration</label> 
<input type="text" name ="time_duration" id ="time_duration" value="">
</form>
```

```js
function timeDuration(){
var start = $('#start_time').val(),
    end = $('#end_time').val(),
    hours = end.split(':')[0] - start.split(':')[0],
    minutes = end.split(':')[1] - start.split(':')[1];

minutes = minutes.toString().length<2?'0'+minutes:minutes;
if(minutes<0){ 
    hours--;
    minutes = 60 + minutes;
}
hours = hours.toString().length<2?'0'+hours:hours;
document.getElementById("time_duration").value = hours + ":" + minutes;

    };
```

Comment: And you tried to code something about it right? Post that code please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between 2 HTML5 time input types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315486/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-2-html5-time-input-types)

Comment: I' ve posted that code

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Tried many times but couldn't get the desired results.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please put yourself in the shoes of someone who doesn't know anything about your problem and provide all necessary context. Currently it's unclear what the problem or the actual question is. What is not working as expected? please try to provide a [mcve], thanks!

Comment: I see you adapted the suggested duplicate, and that it's working... So what can be the *«desired results»*?

Comment: Yes. Its working now. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @lucascaro Thanks for welcoming me here. Actually I had typed wrong spellings for Id in my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you solved it yourself or got the help you needed.
You could also check out node and pre-built npm's like moment. [npm moment](http://momentjs.com/)
Moment has some pre-built functions that already calculate differences between times etc.