# Jquery Date difference in Hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-difference

I am trying to find date difference between 2 dates in hours with out using any 3rd party dates related library. I used the below code but it shows wrong hours. Any better suggestion or pointer to correct this please.

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9wrdctj/1/)

```
var FutureDate=new Date('2016-05-08T05:19:05.83');
var TodayDate = new Date();
var t1 = FutureDate.getTime();
var t2 = TodayDate.getTime();
var diffInHours = parseInt((t2-t1)/(24*3600*1000));
alert(diffInHours);
```

Comment: Why does your formula include `24`? You're trying to convert milliseconds to hours, not to days.

Comment: I am trying to find out how many hours is the difference.

Comment: Yes. And you've got the difference (`t2-t1`) in milliseconds. So, mathematically speaking, how should you convert milliseconds to hours?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields

Comment: Your code produces the difference in *days* instead of hours because of that extra 24.

Comment: var diffInHours = parseInt((t2-t1)/ 1000 / 60 / 60);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var futureDate = new Date('2016-06-08T05:19:05.83');
var todayDate = new Date();
var milliseconds = futureDate.getTime() - todayDate.getTime();
var hours = Math.floor(milliseconds / (60 * 60 * 1000));
alert('Hours: ' + hours);
```

1. hour : minute = 1 : 60
2. minute : second = 1 : 60
3. second : millisecond = 1 : 1000
4. hour: millisecond = 1 : 60x60x1000

Answer (score 1):

You can actually substract dates from each other natively.

```
var msIn1Hour = 3600 * 1000;
var TodayDate = new Date();
var FutureDate = new Date('2016-05-08T05:19:05.83');

alert((TodayDate - FutureDate)/msIn1Hour);
```

Note: I'm not quite sure why you used `parseInt` as this is meant to be used to convert a `string` into a `int`. If you want to round a number, use `Math.floor` or `Math.round`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the divide by 24 from your formula. That 24 is actually converting it to a `difference in days`.

```
t2-t1 = x milliseconds
x/1000 = y seconds
y/3600 = z hours
```

You are done when you have z. So, you dont have to do the divide by 24. So, you can simply write

```
var FutureDate=new Date('2016-05-08T05:19:05.83');
var TodayDate = new Date();
var t1 = FutureDate.getTime();
var t2 = TodayDate.getTime();
var diffInHours = Math.floor((t2-t1)/(3600*1000)); //Removed the 24 here
alert(diffInHours);
```

Comment: as per above comment parseInt may not be a best option.