# calculate the difference between two times js/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

i have this code in php(calculate the difference between "NOW" to another date - in hour,second and minute)

```
$date_now=date("Y-m-d");
$hour_now=date("G:i:s",time() + 3600); // without +3600, i get one hour back from the real time 

$date_time_now = new dateTime($date_now." ".$hour_now);
$date_time_start = new dateTime("2018-06-14"." "."11:46:24");

$diff=$date_time_now->diff($date_time_start);

$hour= $diff->h;
$seconds= $diff->s;
$minutes= $diff ->i;
```

how can i do this calculate in javascript / Jquery ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between dates in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968167/difference-between-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: by momentjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150570/get-hours-difference-between-two-dates-in-moment-js

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date`s in javascript.

To get the `now`-Date you simply do `Date.now()`. To get the date from a specific time you can look into the wonderful [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which says:

```
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hour [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Now you can simply substract both dates and what you get are the difference in milliseconds:

```
Date.now() - new Date(1980, 1, 20) // 20th february 1980
```

Comment: yes, but my problem is to convert the milliseconds to hour,minutes and seconds , so that , for example , 121000 milliseconds will be : 2 minutes and 1 seconds

Comment: well - do the maths. You are a programmer. 1sec = 1000msec; 1min = 60sec; 1h = 60min; 1d = 24h; I am pretty sure you know that!