# Calculate difference between two times and increment the result

Tags: javascript, time, increment

I am trying to calculate the difference between two times and increment the results. For these, I tried below code.

```js
function toSeconds(time_str) {
        // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
        var parts = time_str.split(':');
        // compute  and return total seconds
        return parts[0] * 3600 + // an hour has 3600 seconds
            parts[1] * 60 + // a minute has 60 seconds
            +
            parts[2]; // seconds
    }

    var a = "12:00:00"
    var b = "13:05:02"

    var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(a) - toSeconds(b));

    // format time differnece
    var result = [
        Math.floor(difference / 3600), // an hour has 3600 seconds
        Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60), // a minute has 60 seconds
        difference % 60
    ];
    // 0 padding and concatation
    result = result.map(function (v) {
        return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
    }).join(':');
    alert(result);
```

Assume if start time 00:05 AM and end time 00:10 AM. If we calculate between these two times the result will be 5Minutes right. So we need to increment these like 00:05:00. Now onwards the time will increment from seconds, minutes and then Hours

but it's working if giving **12 Hours** format to calculate remaining hours. Is there any possibility to **calculate the difference between two times and incrementing the result time**.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What's not working?

Comment: Incrementing like what ? The hours or the minutes ?

Comment: Bojjaiah why do your code looks exactly like the answer with 5 votes here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields

Comment: remove `min = ((min / 60) * 100).toString()` and it works fine

Comment: @shreyasminocha Assume if start time **00:05 AM** and end time **00:10 AM**. If we calculate between these two times the result will be **5Minutes** right. So we need to increment these like **00:05:00**. Now onwards the time will increment from seconds, minutes and then Hours. Reference http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1454/jTrack-Time-tracking-app-with-jQuery

Comment: @Hearner Please see above comment.

Comment: What you can do is, you can convert the two time entities to UNIX timestamps. Then take the difference and convert back to the time format you need

Comment: @Bojjaiah What have you tried yourself to solve this?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen see my thread. Calculated time.

Comment: @Bojjaiah That is not what you have tried, that code is the exact match of an answer from another question. I don't see your attempt

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen see updated my thread. need to increment result. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Bojjaiah So once you calculate the difference, you want to countdown those many seconds, am I right? Is that what you mean by "increment"?

Comment: @shreyasminocha see reference link http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/1454/jTrack-Time-tracking-app-with-jQuery

Comment: I'm afraid, I'm still not sure what to make of the demo. Are you trying to replicate the demo? For example once you have calculated the difference, do you want to count up to the difference and display it in `HH:MM:SS` form?

Comment: @shreyasminocha see exactly what I'm looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/6aYzw/590/. Now I need to call this method into my button click. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? I made a function that increments your result variable every 1 second using Javascript's setInterval. You can end the loop by calling `clearInterval(x)`

```js
function toSeconds(time_str) {
        // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
        var parts = time_str.split(':');
        // compute  and return total seconds
        return parts[0] * 3600 + // an hour has 3600 seconds
            parts[1] * 60 + // a minute has 60 seconds
            +
            parts[2]; // seconds
    }

    var a = "12:00:00"
    var b = "13:05:02"

    var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(a) - toSeconds(b));

    // format time differnece
    var result = [
        Math.floor(difference / 3600), // an hour has 3600 seconds
        Math.floor((difference % 3600) / 60), // a minute has 60 seconds
        difference % 60
    ];
    // 0 padding and concatation
//    result = result.map(function (v) {
//        return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
//    }).join(':');
    console.log(result);
    
   let x = setInterval(function() {
   result[2] = result[2] + 1;
   if(result[2]>=60){
    result[2] = 0;
    result[1] = result[1] + 1;
   }
   if(result[1]>=60){
    result[1] = 0;
    result[0] = result[0] +1
    }
    
    result[0] = result[0] === 24 ? 0 : result[0]
      
    console.log(result.map(function (v) {
        return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
    }).join(':'))
  
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: what do you want about AM/PM ? just for display puposes? or part of your calculations?

Comment: i created a code pen for what possibly you might want. You can tidy up some code in there too. https://codepen.io/hibijvs/pen/vaROmr