# Calculate two time with milliseconds using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I have two Times

```
1. 04/20/2021 19:25:20.2522888 + 05:30
2. 04/20/2021 19:25:20.2692870 + 05:30
```

Need to calculate the time difference in JavaScript or Jquery

Format example output : **0:0:0.002**

```js
var startTime = moment("12:16:59 am", "HH:mm:ss a");
var endTime = moment("06:12:07 pm", "HH:mm:ss a");
var duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
var hours = parseInt(duration.asHours());
var minutes = parseInt(duration.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
alert(hours + ' hour and ' + minutes + ' minutes.')

var result = endTime.diff(startTime, 'hours') + " Hrs and " +
  endTime.diff(startTime, 'minutes') + " Mns";
alert(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is already answered in the , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883768/jquery-time-difference-in-hours-from-two-fields

Comment: @RahulShukla That is not correct my expectation.

Comment: If you want it displayed in the format `0:0:0.002` why are you splitting it into hours and minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Convert your custom date string to valid ISO8601 format
- Get the ms difference between your two dates
- Construct a custom response in the format `h*:m:s.ms`

```js
const myDateFormatToISO8601 = str => {
  const [M, D, Y, h, m, s, ms, tzh, tzm] = str.split(/\W+/);
  const ms3 = Math.round(ms / 1e4); // Round ms to 3 integers
  const ISO8601 = `${Y}-${M}-${D}T${h}:${m}:${s}.${ms3}+${tzh}:${tzm}`;
  return new Date(ISO8601);
};

const calcDiff = (Date_a, Date_b) => {
  const a = myDateFormatToISO8601(Date_a);
  const b = myDateFormatToISO8601(Date_b);
  const d = Math.abs(b - a);
  const h = ~~(d / 36e5);
  const m = ~~(d / 6e5) % 60;
  const s = ~~(d / 1e3) % 60;
  const ms = d % 1e3;
  return `${h}:${m}:${s}.${ms}`;
};

// DEMO TIME:

const calculate = () => {
  const a = document.querySelector("#a").value;
  const b = document.querySelector("#b").value;
  document.querySelector("#result").textContent = calcDiff(a, b);
};

document.querySelectorAll(".date").forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("input", calculate));
calculate();
```

```css
input {width: 90%;}
```

```html
<input id="a" class="date" value="04/20/2021 19:25:20.1522888 + 05:30"><br>
<input id="b" class="date" value="04/20/2021 19:25:20.2692870 + 05:30">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply use `diff`

```js
var startTime = moment("19:25:20.2522888","hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
var endTime = moment("19:25:20.2692870","hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
var hrs = endTime.diff(startTime,"hours");
var mins = endTime.diff(startTime,"minutes");
var secs = endTime.diff(startTime,"seconds");
var ms = endTime.diff(startTime,"milliseconds");
console.log(`${hrs}:${mins}:${secs}.${ms.toString().padStart(3,0)}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Please do note though it's [probably time to stop using momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Comment: What if day, month or year are different?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan neither of the 2 examples in the OP had that detail. And the expected format of `0:0:0.002` does not account for it either (being hrs:mins:secs:ms as far as I can tell)

Comment: That's when usually `hh*` take the entire load - since there's no higher `y m d` .